# Webpack - Change 'src' path of javascript files in index.html

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I am facing an issue after building my strapi application (using webpack).

After i executed `yarn build`, my index.html imports javascript files using the `<script>` tag.

The issue comes here, in my build folder, there are all of my files (images, js files etc...), and 0 subfolder.

But inside my index.html, it imports from an invalid path:

```
<script src="admin/file.js"></script>
```

I want to change this src with Webpack to look like that :

```
<script src="./file.js"></script>
```

Anybody got a solution ?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you search the word 'admin' in your project?
maybe some config mistake

Comment: You need to show us webpack's config file

Comment: For some reasons, webpack & strapi aren't coordinated... I put a solution which works for me ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, i found the fix.

I am using Strapi for this web app.

Strapi automatically fills webpack with publicPath "/admin/".

However, webpack doesn't understand and put every files (js, img, html) in the same directory, at the same level (no subfolders).

So inside `src/admin/`, remove the word "example" from the file name "webpack.config.example.js"

Open this file and insert this code

```
'use strict';
module.exports = (config, _webpack) => {
  config = {
    ...config,
    output: { ...config.output, publicPath: './'}
   }
   
  return config;
};
```